Errors in code for limit state function of Monte Carlo simulation
Help! Ive been trying to code this problem for two days and I keep getting errors, there must be an easier way of doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' worked example 6.2b
    Dim NumFails As Long
    Dim Ntrials As Long
    Dim Pi_2 As Double
    Dim Pf As Double
    Dim Beta As Double
    Dim u1 As Double, u2 As Double, u3 As Double
    Dim fb As Double, h As Double, b As Double, w As Double, q As Double
    Dim S As Double, Gx As Double
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Initialize variables
    NumFails = 0
    Ntrials = 10000 ' Number of trials
    Pi_2 = 2 * 3.14159265358979
    Randomize
    
    ' Statistical properties
    Dim mean_fb As Double, cov_fb As Double, std_fb As Double
    Dim mean_h As Double, cov_h As Double, std_h As Double
    Dim mean_b As Double, cov_b As Double, std_b As Double
    Dim mean_w As Double, cov_w As Double, std_w As Double
    Dim mean_q As Double, cov_q As Double, std_q As Double
    Dim L As Double
    
    mean_fb = 30 ' N/mm²
    cov_fb = 0.15
    std_fb = mean_fb * cov_fb
    
    mean_h = 757 ' mm
    cov_h = 0.04
    std_h = mean_h * cov_h
    
    mean_b = 250 ' mm
    cov_b = 0.03
    std_b = mean_b * cov_b
    
    mean_w = 20 ' kN/m
    cov_w = 0.1
    std_w = mean_w * cov_w
    
    mean_q = 15 ' kN/m
    cov_q = 0.18
    std_q = mean_q * cov_q
    
    L = 8000 ' Beam span in mm (8m)
    
    ' Monte Carlo Simulation
    For i = 1 To Ntrials
        ' Generate random variables
        u1 = Rnd
        u2 = Rnd
        u3 = Rnd

        ' Generate lognormal random variable
        Dim mu_fb As Double, sigma_fb As Double
        mu_fb = Log(mean_fb / Sqr(1 + (std_fb / mean_fb) ^ 2))
        sigma_fb = Sqr(Log(1 + (std_fb / mean_fb) ^ 2))
        h = mean_h + std_h * Sqr(-2 * Log(Rnd)) * Cos(Pi_2 * Rnd)
        b = mean_b + std_b * Sqr(-2 * Log(Rnd)) * Cos(Pi_2 * Rnd)
        w = mean_w + std_w * Sqr(-2 * Log(Rnd)) * Cos(Pi_2 * Rnd)
        q = mean_q - (std_q / 0.5772) * Log(-Log(u3))
        
        ' Section modulus
        S = (b * (h ^ 2)) / 6
        
        ' Evaluate limit state function
        Gx = fb * S - ((w + q) * (L ^ 2)) / 8
        
        ' Count failures
        If Gx < 0 Then
            NumFails = NumFails + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Probability of failure and safety index
    Pf = NumFails / Ntrials
    Beta = -Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(Pf)
    
    ' Output results
    Range("C8").Value = Ntrials
    Range("C10").Value = NumFails
    Range("C12").Value = Pf
    Range("C14").Value = Sqr((1 - Pf) / (Ntrials - 1) / Pf) ' COV of Pf
    Range("C16").Value = Beta
End Sub

I've been trying to code this problem, I have calculated this by hand and came up with a Probability of failure of 2.3e-4 and a safety factor beta of 3.5, but am constantly getting errors particularly around the beta = - application line, it doesn't seen to want to calculate figures below 0

Dim Beta As Variant: Beta = Application.Norm_S_Inv then check using IsError(Beta) to see whether you got a numeric return value, or an error (such as for example when Pf = 1).  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.norm_s_inv   FYI - dropping the WorksheetFunction prevents a run-time error and instead allows the function to return an error value.

While not critical Pi_2 = 2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi() might be better than Pi_2 = 2 * 3.14159265358979

Your calculation of Gx seems to be incorrect, because the variable fb is not being explicitly assigned a value during the loop. If my understanding is correct you should add fb = Exp(mu_fb + sigma_fb * Sqr(-2 * Log(Rnd)) * Cos(Pi_2 * Rnd)) after you calculate mu_fb and sigma_fb. Otherwise fb is always zero (which happend to you).
I also added the suggestions of Tim Williams and Michal and get a beta value of 3,43161440362327.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' worked example 6.2b
Dim NumFails As Long
Dim Ntrials As Long
Dim Pi_2 As Double
Dim Pf As Double
Dim Beta As Variant
Dim u1 As Double, u2 As Double, u3 As Double
Dim fb As Double, h As Double, b As Double, w As Double, q As Double
Dim S As Double, Gx As Double
Dim i As Long

' Initialize variables
NumFails = 0
Ntrials = 10000 ' Number of trials
Pi_2 = 2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()
Randomize

' Statistical properties
Dim mean_fb As Double, cov_fb As Double, std_fb As Double
Dim mean_h As Double, cov_h As Double, std_h As Double
Dim mean_b As Double, cov_b As Double, std_b As Double
Dim mean_w As Double, cov_w As Double, std_w As Double
Dim mean_q As Double, cov_q As Double, std_q As Double
Dim L As Double

mean_fb = 30 ' N/mm²
cov_fb = 0.15
std_fb = mean_fb * cov_fb

mean_h = 757 ' mm
cov_h = 0.04
std_h = mean_h * cov_h

mean_b = 250 ' mm
cov_b = 0.03
std_b = mean_b * cov_b

mean_w = 20 ' kN/m
cov_w = 0.1
std_w = mean_w * cov_w

mean_q = 15 ' kN/m
cov_q = 0.18
std_q = mean_q * cov_q

L = 8000 ' Beam span in mm (8m)

' Monte Carlo Simulation
For i = 1 To Ntrials
    ' Generate random variables
    u1 = Rnd
    u2 = Rnd
    u3 = Rnd

    ' Generate lognormal random variable
    Dim mu_fb As Double, sigma_fb As Double
    mu_fb = Log(mean_fb / Sqr(1 + (std_fb / mean_fb) ^ 2))
    sigma_fb = Sqr(Log(1 + (std_fb / mean_fb) ^ 2))
    fb = Exp(mu_fb + sigma_fb * Sqr(-2 * Log(Rnd)) * Cos(Pi_2 * Rnd))
    h = mean_h + std_h * Sqr(-2 * Log(Rnd)) * Cos(Pi_2 * Rnd)
    b = mean_b + std_b * Sqr(-2 * Log(Rnd)) * Cos(Pi_2 * Rnd)
    w = mean_w + std_w * Sqr(-2 * Log(Rnd)) * Cos(Pi_2 * Rnd)
    q = mean_q - (std_q / 0.5772) * Log(-Log(u3))
    
    ' Section modulus
    S = (b * (h ^ 2)) / 6
    
    ' Evaluate limit state function
    Gx = fb * S - ((w + q) * (L ^ 2)) / 8
    
    ' Count failures
    If Gx < 0 Then
        NumFails = NumFails + 1
    End If
Next i

' Probability of failure and safety index
Pf = NumFails / Ntrials
Beta = -Application.Norm_S_Inv(Pf)

' Output results
Range("C8").Value = Ntrials
Range("C10").Value = NumFails
Range("C12").Value = Pf
Range("C14").Value = Sqr((1 - Pf) / (Ntrials - 1) / Pf) ' COV of Pf
Range("C16").Value = Beta
End Sub


thanks guys, that works a treat! I see where the error was in the G(X) now, its like everything, when you have been looking at something for ages, its hard to see the errors.
